# Error:1064, ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

What should I change?
This is my statement:

```
sql = "SELECT 'housing_median_age', 'median_income' FROM 'california_housing_test' WHERE 'population' = 850"
cur.execute(sql)
result = cur.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Comment: If you're wondering, those examples that you saw are using backticks (`\``) and not single-quote (`'`)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL identifiers don't take single quotes.  Remove them:

```
sql = ""SELECT housing_median_age, median_income
        FROM california_housing_test
        WHERE population = 850"""
cur.execute(sql)
result = cur.fetchall()
print(result)
```